# How to apply the correct syntax for IF condition with HTML for Swiftmailer?

Tags: php, syntax, swiftmailer

I needed to upgrade my PHP online form from 5.3 to 7.2.  Decided to use Swiftmailer and have it setup to send emails.  Now I need to reproduce the same email as I had it.  When I copy over PHP code from the older version, I am running into some syntax errors that I don't understand.  Here is the code:

```
<?php

// Varibles for the general information section
$company_name = $_REQUEST['company_name'];
$contact = $_REQUEST['contact'];
$delivery_date = $_REQUEST['delivery_date'];
$delivery_time = $_REQUEST['delivery_time'];
$delivery_address = $_REQUEST['delivery_address'];
$phone = $_REQUEST['phone'];
$special_instruction = $_REQUEST['special_instruction'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$payment = $_REQUEST['payment'];


require_once '[localhosting_service]/phpmailer/vendor/autoload.php';

// Create the Transport
$transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('********.com', ***, 'ssl'))
->setUsername('******@********.com')
->setPassword('[password]')
;

// Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);

// Create a message
$message = (new Swift_Message('Wonderful Subject'))
->setFrom(['******@*******.com' => '!!! Online Order !!!'])
->setTo(['********@*****.com' => 'Jake'])
->setCc(['********@*****.com' => 'Jay'])

->setSubject('Online order from A COMPANY')

->setBody('<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<body>
<p>You have an order from a visitor (<strong>'.$company_name.'</strong>) on your website:</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>*** General Information ***</strong></p>
<p>
<strong>Company Name:</strong> <span style="color:red;">'.$company_name.'</span><br />';
if (!empty($contact))
  {
    $message->setBody .= '<strong>Contact:</strong> <span style="color:red;">'.$contact.'</span><br />';
  }
$message->setBody .= '<strong>Delivery Date:</strong> <span style="color:red;">'.$delivery_date.'</span><br />
<strong>Delivery Time:</strong> <span style="color:red;">'.$delivery_time.'</span><br />
<strong>Delivery Address:</strong> <span style="color:red;">'.$delivery_address.'</span><br />
<strong>Phone:</strong> <span style="color:red;">'.$phone.'</span><br />';
if (!empty($special_instruction))
  {
    $message->setBody .= '<strong>Special Instruction:</strong> <span style="color:red;">'.$special_instruction.'</span><br />';
  }
$message->setBody .= '<strong>Email:</strong> <span style="color:red;">'.$email.'</span><br />
<strong>Type of Payment:</strong> <span style="color:red;">'.$payment.'</span><br />
</p>
</body>
</html>')
;

// Send the message
$result = $mailer->send($message);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by defining the `$body` email outside its setter method. "Build it" before, and once you have it defined, then pass it as an argument to the `setBody()` method.

Look at this example:

```php
// ...
$body = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<body>
<p>You have an order from a visitor (<strong>' . $company_name . '</strong>) on your website:</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>*** General Information ***</strong></p>
<p>
<strong>Company Name:</strong> <span style="color:red;">' . $company_name . '</span><br />';
if (!empty($contact)) {
    $body.='<strong>Contact:</strong> <span style="color:red;">' . $contact . '</span><br />';
}
$body.='<strong>Delivery Date:</strong> <span style="color:red;">' . $delivery_date . '</span><br />
<strong>Delivery Time:</strong> <span style="color:red;">' . $delivery_time . '</span><br />
<strong>Delivery Address:</strong> <span style="color:red;">' . $delivery_address . '</span><br />
<strong>Phone:</strong> <span style="color:red;">' . $phone . '</span><br />';
if (!empty($special_instruction)) {
    $body.='<strong>Special Instruction:</strong> <span style="color:red;">' . $special_instruction . '</span><br />';
}
$body.='<strong>Email:</strong> <span style="color:red;">' . $email . '</span><br />
<strong>Type of Payment:</strong> <span style="color:red;">' . $payment . '</span><br />
</p>
</body>
</html>';

$message = (new \Swift_Message('Wonderful Subject'))
    ->setFrom(['******@*******.com' => '!!! Online Order !!!'])
    ->setTo(['********@*****.com' => 'Jake'])
    ->setCc(['********@*****.com' => 'Jay'])
    ->setSubject('Online order from A COMPANY')
    ->setBody($body);

$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

That said, I recommend you to use the new [Symfony Mailer component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/mailer.html). It's super easy to create messages and use them with different mailers! :)

Comment: Thank you @Chemaclass for your solution...   I applied it and received an Fatal Error:
Fatal error: Uncaught Swift_TransportException: Connection could not be established with host classicboxlunches.com [ #0] in /../../../phpmailer/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php:269 Stack trace: #0 

Not sure what cause this as it is beyond my skills in PHP.  Let me know if there is anything more I can provide.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you install and use the SymfonyMailer component (using composer)? Read their docu and try it out, it's super trivial and you will see results quickly. Because the error that you mention says it's somehow related with the Swift_Transport, that might be because some misconfiguration. Are you sure all the Param are well settled?